# Python matching words with same index in string

Tags: python, string, matching

I have two strings of equal length and want to match words that have the same index. I am also attempting to match consecutive matches which is where I am having trouble.

For example I have two strings

```
alligned1 = 'I am going to go to some show'
alligned2 = 'I am not going to go the show'
```

What I am looking for is to get the result:

```
['I am','show']
```

My current code is as follow:

```
keys = []
for x in alligned1.split():
    for i in alligned2.split():
        if x == i:
            keys.append(x)
```

Which gives me:

```
['I','am','show']
```

Any guidance or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finding matching words is fairly simple, but putting them in contiguous groups is fairly tricky. I suggest using `groupby`.

```
import itertools

alligned1 = 'I am going to go to some show'
alligned2 = 'I am not going to go the show'

results = []
word_pairs = zip(alligned1.split(), alligned2.split())
for k, v in itertools.groupby(word_pairs, key = lambda pair: pair[0] == pair[1]):
    if k: 
        words = [pair[0] for pair in v]
        results.append(" ".join(words))

print results
```

Result:

```
['I am', 'show']
```

Comment: Nice. This is the only answer that actually answers the question!

Comment: Great answer! Can you think of a way without using imports, just as an alternative? (I'm trying)

Comment: I had a clunky answer that worked, which just goes to show how useful the itertools module is. Nice job!

Comment: @BhargavRao, you could always just copy-paste the implementation of [groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). Then you wouldn't need an import ;-) If that was also disallowed, I'd probably use a flag to keep track of whether the previous pair was a match or not. Similar to Matt Davidson's answer.

Comment: Great answer @BhargavRao my answer does the same without itertools.

Comment: @MattDavidson Oops, I did hadn't seen your answer then. Your's looks very neat and clean (I added my approach as an answer too!)

Answer (score 3):

A simplification of your code would be:

```
alligned1 = 'I am going to go to some show'
alligned2 = 'I am not going to go the show'

keys = []
for i, word in enumerate(alligned1.split()): 
    if word == alligned2.split()[i]:
        keys.append(word)
```

We then need to track if we have just matched a word, let's do it with a flag variable.

```
alligned1 = 'I am going to go to some show'
alligned2 = 'I am not going to go the show'

keys = []
prev = ''
for i, word in enumerate(alligned1.split()): 
    if word == alligned2.split()[i]:
        prev = prev + ' ' + word if prev else word

    elif prev:
        keys.append(prev)
        prev = ''
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Check now please, sorry don't have an isntall to check it with

Comment: `alligned2.split()[i]` Why are you splitting every time?

Comment: @MattDavidson Why don't use online compiler services like ideone.com?

Answer (score 1):

Well [Kevin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29776365/4099593) is the best and spot on. I tried to do it teh brute force way. It does not look good, but does the job, without any *imports*

```
alligned1 = 'I am going to go to some show'.split(' ')
alligned2 = 'I am not going to go the show'.split(' ')
keys = []
temp = [v if v==alligned1[i] else None for i,v in enumerate(alligned2) ]
temp.append(None)
tmpstr = ''
for i in temp:
    if i:
        tmpstr+=i+' '
    else:
        if tmpstr: keys.append(tmpstr)
        tmpstr = ''
keys =  [i.strip() for i in keys]
print keys
```

Output

```
['I am', 'show']
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not very elegant, but it works:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

alligned1 = 'I am going to go to some show'
alligned2 = 'I am not going to go the show'

curr_match = ''
matches = []
for w1, w2 in izip_longest(alligned1.split(), alligned2.split()):
    if w1 != w2:
        if curr_match:
            matches.append(curr_match)
            curr_match = ''
        continue
    if curr_match:
        curr_match += ' '
    curr_match += w1
if curr_match:
    matches.append(curr_match)

print matches
```

result:

```
['I am', 'show']
```